# Meaning of タッグでやる

Tags: nuances, expressions, idioms, business-japanese

According to Wikipedia, a [tag team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_team) is a two-person team of which only one person plays at a time.

Speaking of a long-length work project, 小林 says:

> 田中とタッグでやる。

Is there any nuance difference with `田中と2人のチームでやる`?

In particular, is there any nuance that only one of them works at a time?

Answer (score 2):

There is only a small difference in nuance between 「タッグ」 and 「チーム」, which I honestly would not have even thought about had I not encountered this question.

「タッグ」 would often connote a somewhat closer relationship required between the two persons for the project than 「チーム」 would.  IMHO, this is because the word 「タッグ」 is drived from an aggressive contact sport of pro-wrestling.

「チーム」, to me, sounds more "sophisticated" (or in Japanese, 「よりスマートな[感]{かん}じ」) than 「タッグ」 does at least when used in business situations.